# How to link a certain/specific page on a PDF document to a certain word/number on a Word doc?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, ms-word

How would I link a specific page on a PDF document to a certain word/number on a word doc?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:-

1. On the menu bar, select Tools > Advanced Editing > Link Tool.Your mouse cursor will change from the hand cursor ( ) to . Use this tool to click and drag, drawing a box around the text that you want to link.
2. Once you have completed drawing the box, release the mouse button. The Create Link dialog box will display.
3. Select the Open a page in this document option.
4. In the Page field, type in the page number of the page you want the link to jump to when clicked.

**Note**: Make sure you type in the actual page number of the page to which you want to link. You can determine the correct page number by going to the page you want to link to, and then look at the bottom of the Adobe Acrobat screen ( ) to see what page you're on.

5. Click OK to apply the settings or click Cancel to exit without applying the settings.

After clicking OK in the above steps, the box that you drew around the text to link will display in
red. You can adjust the width and height of the box if you need to by clicking and dragging each
side of the box. If you want to change the appearance of the link, go to the "Adjusting the
Appearance of the Link" section of this document.

I hope that helps!